# Programs disappearing after being minimized

Tags: 11.04, unity

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 yesterday using the Wubi installer and I've noticed that a few of my programs will disappear when I minimize them. For example, I can't minimize Eclipse because it will disappear and I won't be able the load a 2nd one because the 1st is using my workspace (if you're familiar with Eclipse you know that you can't use the same workplace twice as the same time). I also just noticed that if I minimize a terminal then it will disappear as well.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and what, if anything, I can do to prevent it?

Comment: When you say disappear, you mean its icon also vanishes from the launcher?

Comment: Unless I have ticked off the box that keeps the icon in the launcher after I close the program, yes. If I do have this box ticked then clicking the launcher icon will load another instance of the program.

Comment: Just happened to me on Ubuntu 13.04: Netbeans 7.3 simply disappeared after minimizing! (of course **it was also missing from Alt-Tab**: it's not that simple, Peter). Even more weird: the Netbeans icon locked to the Unity Dock bar was now launching Gedit... Could not find any other solution than restart, after which everything went back to normal: minimizing, alt-tab and the Dock icon of Netbeans was working again - but I don't trust this #&@# Unity anymore, I also installed Avant Windows Navigator just in case. I love the features of Ubuntu 13.04, but Windows 7 was much more reliable on the sa

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue as well, but for me it was solved by taking AllTray out of the equation. You didn't happen to have the programs set to automatically minimize to the system tray, did you? If you did, the tray requires the applications to be white-listed now.

Instead of just denying it, it seems to just hide the program completely. Almost as if alltray was doing it's job, but being denied an icon spot in the tray.

Answer (score 3):

For me this worked:
pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) pops up the running programs, including the minimized ones that I can't access with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my 64-bit Ubuntu system by adding an applet for Avant Windows Navigator called Launcher/taskmanager.  Now every time I shrink a window it appears on the AWN bar.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution...it only works in the Ubuntu Unity interface and NOT Classic...I used the first solution listed: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, I went to **Windows** --> **Preferences**. In the **General** tab I selected **Always run background**. It would not surprise me if something similar worked in other programs.

Answer (score 1):

you can try following these steps:

1. right click on panel
2. add to panel
3. task bar (windows list)

for permanent view of all the open windows in the active taskbar/workspace..

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any of that - simple ALT-TAB and when you get to your App you'll see all the open screens - just tab to the one you want. Ok, it could be easier...

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar problem in 12.04, with workspaces - windows would (seemingly randomly) disappear, and it would turn out that they were in a different workspace. The standard `Alt+Tab` combination is designed to only take windows from the currently active workspace.

There are a couple of ways you can see if this is the case:

1. Open up the workspace switcher, and see if the missing windows are there. From the switcher (in 12.04; I don't know whether the behaviour is the same in 11.04) you can drag any open windows into the desired workspace.
2. Use `Ctrl+Alt+Tab` instead of just `Alt+Tab`. This will switch between windows in all workspaces, not just the active one.

If you want a more permanent solution (indeed, if this *is* what's happening) and don't use multiple workspaces, you can disable the extras using e.g. Ubuntu Tweak (`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`) - under Tweaks->Workspace, set the "Horizontal workspace" and "Vertical workspace" settings to 1 each.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the login screen to Ubuntu Classic, after you login there is a small icon in the left bottom (bottom panel), right click near the icon go to `preferences`, select  `show windows from all work spaces`.
That's it, you will be able to view the minimized windows :)

Answer (score -1):

Right click on panel - select *add to panel* - scroll down and chose *windows list 
all file minimize* - will show on panel.

Comment: I cannot grok this assemblage of words ; perhaps edit?